# setValue not working with Controller in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using `react-hook-form` with `MUI components`. To use the `Select` component, I have wrapped it in the `Controller` as it can't be **registered** directly. Everything is working but `setValue`.

Here is the Code:

```js
const { register, control, handleSubmit, setValue, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
     setValue('category',10)
  }, [setValue]);

<Controller
  name="category"
  control={control}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <>
      <TextField
        {...field}
        select
        label={'Item Category'}
      >
        <MenuItem value={''} disabled>Select Category</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </TextField>

    </>
  )}
  />
```

I am expecting my Selector category to get updated on the initial load.

Update: One thing I found is that actually the value is being set on the load but not being rendered on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself:

Needed to set the `defaultValue` either in the controller or in the `useForm` default value.

```js
  <Controller
    name="category"
    control={control}
    defaultValue='' //Must set this otherwise setValue won't trigger re-render
    rules={constraints.category}
    render={({ field }) => (..myComponent..)}
  />
```